# Can not show output as required in PHP website through MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I first want to show a **question** then its respective **answers** from two different tables. My code is as follows:

```
$reg = $_SESSION['reg'];

 $sql1="select users.reg,questions.question,questions.id 
        from users,questions 
        where users.reg=questions.reg 
        and questions.company='infosys' 
        and questions.reg!='$reg' 
        limit 0,5";

  $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

  $sql2="select answers.id,answers.reg,answers.answer from answers";
  $query2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
  {
    echo "<p class='fill'>".$row1["reg"]."asked:-" ;
    echo '<br>QID:-'.$row1['id'].'&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row1["question"].'"<br></p>';
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
        {
            if($row1['id']==$row2['id'])
            {
                echo "<pre align='right'>".$row2["reg"]."answered:-" ;
                echo '<br>'.$row2['id'].'&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row2["answer"].'"</pre>';  
            }
        }
```

I can only display the answers to the first **Question**. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: If you want us to understand what's happening, you need to show us your database schema and some example data. You should also look into using sql-"JOIN"'s instead of comma separating multiple tables in your query.

Comment: if you want join two tables there must be a common filed... in your questions&answer table there is no common id i guess, and if yes join the two tables with that foreign key then write where condition for question id

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have issue in your code. Once you traverse from executed query, It will not traverse from loop again until you execute query again. So you can store your result in array then you can traverse from it

```
<?php
$reg = $_SESSION['reg'];
  $sql1="select users.reg,questions.question,questions.id from users,questions where users.reg=questions.reg and questions.company='infosys' and questions.reg!='$reg' limit 0,5";
  $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

  $sql2="select answers.id,answers.reg,answers.answer from answers";
  $query2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

  //traverse naswer loops
  $answers = array();
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){ 
    $answers[] = $row2;        
  }

  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
    echo "<p class='fill'>".$row1["reg"]."asked:-" ;
    echo '<br>QID:-'.$row1['id'].'&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row1["question"].'"<br></p>';
    foreach($answers as $answer)
        if($row1['id']==$answer['id']){
            echo "<pre align='right'>".$answer["reg"]."answered:-" ;
            echo '<br>'.$answer['id'].'&emsp;&emsp;"'.$answer["answer"].'"</pre>';  
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Yeah it Worked!! @B. Desai.

Comment: @Pro if its working then upvote and accept the answer so that it can help other

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all questions. Loop through them and get the relevant answers in the loop itself by passing question's ID in where condition. By this you will make sure you get all the relevant answers to the question.

something like following?

```
$reg = $_SESSION['reg'];
$sql1="select users.reg,questions.question,questions.id from users,questions where users.reg=questions.reg and questions.company='infosys' and questions.reg!='$reg' limit 0,5";
$query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
echo "<p class='fill'>".$row1["reg"]."asked:-" ;
echo '<br>QID:-'.$row1['id'].'&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row1["question"].'"<br></p>';

    $sql2="select answers.id,answers.reg,answers.answer from answers where questionid = ".$row1['id'];
    $query2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
            echo "<pre align='right'>".$row2["reg"]."answered:-" ;
            echo '<br>'.$row2['id'].'&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row2["answer"].'"  </pre>';  
    }
  }
```